# How do I change inside app icon in windows 7 and windows 10?

Tags: windows, icons

Recently I downloaded an app and I wanted to change its icon.

I've changed the icon of the app using a right click --> properties --> change icon, but it only changes the icon that is being showed in task bar or app location, i.e. when I open the app, app's default icon is being showed.

Is it possible to change the inside app (the icons inside the app) icons?

I've tried changing the .ico files inside application path but it didn't work. I've also tried changing it using resourceHacker but it just cause errors.